# mysql query that takes sequence into account

Tags: mysql

- Search Term a: black small rock
- Search Term b: black rock small
- Search Term c: small rock black

I want to design a query that will take the order in which the terms are written into account.  Now I'd like the above three terms to produce the same results, but I want order of the results to reflect the sequence of the terms.

I only hope this makes sense; please let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't make sense. Do you have a specific query or search code you want to change. SQL, as a general rule, has no natural language search so the concept of search term ordering is meaningless without further explanation or your existing search code.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired result sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see this working is if you are separating the search terms as attributes, in the database table, in those specific order.

- Attribute 1: black
- Attribute 2: small
- Attribute 3: rock

In which case, the query for your first search term "black small rock" would match "black" in Attributes 1, 2, **or** 3 and then perform the same logical-or operation for the other two fields in the search term.

Your query, would actually be rather simple:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (attr1 = 'black' OR attr2 = 'black' OR attr3 = 'black')
AND (attr1 = 'small' OR attr2 = 'small' OR attr3 = 'small')
AND (attr1 = 'rock' OR attr2 = 'rock' OR attr3 = 'rock');
```

At which point, you rely on the logic in the programming language you are issuing this query from to order the displayed data by search term, where you test the first attribute (Python-like pseudocode):

```
search_terms = split(search_term, " ")
ordered_results = [
   [x for x in results if x["attr1"] == search_terms[0]],
   [y for y in results if x["attr2"] == search_terms[1]],
   [z for z in results if z["attr3"] == search_terms[2]]
]
for result_set in ordered_results:
   for r in result_set:
      # Display the result.
```